# how can I INSERT a random Point with X|Y which is not yet in my Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

Yeah.

I have some bases in coordinates. they are all around the center. Now I want to add one more base, at unique coordinates, near the other bases. I have thought about that so far:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`base`
    (`idbase`, `coordinate_X`, `coordinate_Y`)
    VALUES (NULL,
            '(FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *((select max(coordinate_X))+1)))',
            '(FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *((select max(coordinate_Y))+1)))'
           );
```

idbase is autoincrement, thats why I insert NULL

This so far is how I could choose a point in the area I want them to have. I allready thought of making an unique index with the coordinates. But how can I go sure, that a new base is created at a new point?

I would prefer not doing it with a while-loop in php, i think that wouldnt be a nice sollution.

EDIT:

that did not even work, i cant make a subselect in that insert statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to tell:

I solved it in PHP:

```
function newbase($user)//create a new base for given user
{
    $mycon = createconnection();
    $sql = "SELECT max(abs(coordinate_X)+1) as X,max(abs(coordinate_Y)+1) as Y FROM `base`";
    $range = $mycon->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();

    do
    {
    $coordinateX = rand(-$range['X'], $range['X']);
    $coordinateY = rand(-$range['Y'], $range['Y']);//get random coordinates
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `inetphan_gibb`.`base` (`idbase`, `coordinate_X`, `coordinate_Y`, `name`, `user_iduser`) VALUES (NULL, '$coordinateX', '$coordinateY', 'Just a unnamed base', '{$user['iduser']}');";
    $mycon->query($sql);
    } while ($mycon->affected_rows < 1);//repeat until a row is affected

    $mycon->close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `INSERT..SELECT` construct instead of ill-formed subqueries in side quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`base`
    (`idbase`, `coordinate_X`, `coordinate_Y`)
    SELECT NULL,
           FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * (max(coordinate_X)+1) ),
           FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * (max(coordinate_Y)+1) )
        FROM mydb.base;
```